# Using a custom Lock Screen does not unlock the SIM (PIN)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, sim-card

When using [Hi Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.appplus.hilocker) as my lock screen, my Android Lollipop device does not prompt me for my SIM PIN upon boot -- and leaves the SIM card locked (therefore providing no service).

## Details:

I'm running a rooted stock Android Lollipop 5.0.2 on an Xperia Z1 compact (firmware build number 14.5.A.0.242).

I replaced the system lock screen with Hi Locker, i.e. *Settings -> Security -> Screen lock* is set to *None* and Hi Locker is enabled with "password" (it's also a PIN, but to avoid confusion with the SIM PIN, let's refer to this as password).

The device is not encrypted.

When I reboot the device, no mobile service is available and the notification bar shows "SIM card is locked. -- Emergency calls only."

I am not prompted for the SIM PIN at any point during or after boot, even after unlocking (and relocking) the device with the Hi Locker password.

**To double check**, I have done and found out the following:

- I can get the SIM PIN upon boot as long as Hi Locker is disabled.
- If Hi Locker was enabled during boot, I can get to the SIM PIN prompt in the following way (without rebooting):

  - disable Hi Locker
  - enable system Screen Lock (*with security*, 'Swipe' alone does not work)
  - lock device
  - upon next unlock, SIM PIN is required

*Note:* I have searched both on Google and here, but have found no reports of similar issues. So either this is a weird problem, or most people don't use PIN locks, or my search terms were too far off the mark.

## Question:

I would like to **keep my SIM PIN enabled** for the added security.

Is there any way to make sure the PIN is prompted and the SIM unlocked upon boot, even when using a custom lock screen?

Comment: Same problem here with Exodus on OPO. Note that the same problem insists with other lockscreen apps. (I tried Hi Locker and CM Locker.)

Answer (score 1):

The system lock screen needs to be enabled in order for you to be prompted with the SIM pin. Unfortunately, 3rd party lock screens won't work with this feature unless the system lock screen is also enabled. One workaround would be to find (or write) an app that uses the 'disable your screen lock' permission constantly to ensure that the system lockscreen never appears but remains enabled in Settings, thus allowing you to use the SIM lock.